# Why is str_ireplace behaving unexpectedly and duplicating data for just one needle?

Tags: php

I have wrote a small piece of code for converting some food ingredients from the US format to international format.

To achieve this, I am using `str_ireplace`. This is working for everything except the needle "Blue 1". The expected output is `Brilliant blue (E133) *` but the actual output is `Brilliant blue (E133) * (E133) *`

Why is `str_ireplace` adding another `(E133) *` to the end of the string?

```
$ingredients = "Blue 1";

$find_colors = array(
    'Allura red',
    'Food Red 17',
    'C.I. 16035',
    'Red 40',
    'Carmoisine',
    'Azorubine',
    'Food Red 3',
    'Azorubin S',
    'Brilliantcarmoisin O',
    'Red 14',
    'C.I. 14720',
    'Ponceau 4R',
    'Cochineal Red A',
    'C.I. 16255',
    'Acid Red 18',
    'Brilliant Scarlet 3R',
    'Brilliant Scarlet 4R',
    'New Coccine',
    'SX Purple',
    'Quinoline yellow',
    'C.I. 47005',
    'Yellow 13',
    'Acid Yellow 3',
    'Sunset yellow',
    'Yellow 6',
    'C.I. 15985',
    'Tartrazine',
    'Yellow 5',
    'Blue 1',
    'Brilliant Blue',
    'Acid Blue 9',
    'Blue 2',
    'Yellow #5',
    'C.I. 19140',
    'red 3'
);
$replace_colors = array(
    'Allura red (E129) *',
    'Allura red (E129) *',
    'Allura red (E129) *',
    'Allura red (E129) *',
    'Carmoisine (E122) *',
    'Carmoisine (E122) *',
    'Carmoisine (E122) *',
    'Carmoisine (E122) *',
    'Carmoisine (E122) *',
    'Carmoisine (E122) *',
    'Carmoisine (E122) *',
    'Ponceau 4R (E124) *',
    'Ponceau 4R (E124) *',
    'Ponceau 4R (E124) *',
    'Ponceau 4R (E124) *',
    'Ponceau 4R (E124) *',
    'Ponceau 4R (E124) *',
    'Ponceau 4R (E124) *',
    'Ponceau 4R (E124) *',
    'Quinoline yellow (E104) *',
    'Quinoline yellow (E104) *',
    'Quinoline yellow (E104) *',
    'Quinoline yellow (E104) *',
    'Sunset yellow (E110) *',
    'Sunset yellow (E110) *',
    'Sunset yellow (E110) *',
    'Tartrazine (E102) *',
    'Tartrazine (E102) *',
    'Brilliant blue (E133) *',
    'Brilliant blue (E133) *',
    'Brilliant blue (E133) *',
    'Indigo carmine (E132) *',
    'Tartrazine (E102) *',
    'Tartrazine (E102) *',
    'Allura red (E129) *'
);

$ingredients = str_ireplace($find_colors, $replace_colors, $ingredients);

echo $ingredients;
```

This behaviour does not seem to occur with any other needle. Additionally, if I remove all other needles and haystack, the issue does not occur.

Why is `str_ireplace` repeating these characters?

Comment: It's because you also have *Brilliant Blue* as an option, which if finds once you replace *blue 1* with *Brilliant blue (E133) \**

Comment: Thank you, this did not occur to me as a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you also have *Brilliant Blue* as an option, which if finds once you replace *blue 1* with *Brilliant blue (E133) **.

This simplest solution is to always look for the longest replacement string first, so switch the options...

```
'Brilliant Blue',
'Blue 1',
```